# Problem connecting MySQL to Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
I have a Rails application and I am getting this error. I have no idea how to find mysql connect it to mysql.sock. I am pretty sure i can go into config/database.yml and set the mysql.sock but where is it or do I need to reinstall it?

When I do locate mysql i get alot of results including the two below

```
/usr/include/mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
```

but when I locate mysql.sock I get nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is mysql actually running, and set to listen on the socket interface.  Make sure that the server is started/configured.

well first check to see if it is running

```
ps auxwww | grep mysql
```

should do that, if not, then

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

or

```
service mysql start
```

as root (or via sudo, should start it). but if it is running the socket should be in

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: well first check to see if it is running (ps auxwww | grep mysql) should do that, if not, then /etc/init.d/mysql start  as root (or via sudo, should start it).  but if it is running the socket should be in /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock